# Little o notation question with the prime number theory?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I don't understand what is being used in the little o notation for a description of the Prime Number Theorem. Specifically I do not understand what is f(x) or g(x) for their little o notation which they state as:

> "The Prime Number Theorem states the number of primes at most x is
> Li(x) + o(Li(x))
>
> where Li(x) is the integral from 2 to x  of [dt/logt]
>
> and the notation f(x) = og(x) means as the limit of x approaches
> infinity of [f(x)/g(x) = 0]."

I am confused here what is supposed to be f(x) or g(x) for the little o notation. I understand they used Li(x) to be the offset logarithmic integral but is Li(x) the f(x) and if so what is g(x)? I am confused because I thought of the PMT to be Li(x) - pi(x) = O(sqrt(x)logx) or maybe Li(x) ~ pi(x) and I'm not sure how I would get there from this little o notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we write $\pi(x)=\mathrm{Li}(x)+o(\mathrm{Li}(x))$ we mean that if $f(x)=\pi(x)-\mathrm{Li}(x)$ then $f(x)=o(\mathrm{Li}(x))$.

Equivalently, $\pi(x)=(1+o(1))\mathrm{Li}(x)$. In general, this is using the convention that when I write $o(g(x))$ I mean implicitly that there exists some function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=o(g(x))$ which can be placed into the equation.

Finally, you are correct that the Prime Number Theorem is that $\pi(x)\sim \mathrm{Li}(x)$. The other statement you make, that $\mathrm{Li}(x)-\pi(x)=O(x^{1/2}\log x)$ is much stronger, and is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis.